# Unable to start tungsten replicator service

Tags: mysql, tungsten-replicator

I am trying to set master-master Tungsten replication between servers. ./tools/tpm install command installed successfully and replicator is also started but when trying to look at services i was getting below output.

```
Processing services command...
NAME              VALUE
----              -----
appliedLastSeqno: Unknown
appliedLatency  : Unknown
role            : Unknown
serviceName     : alpha
serviceType     : Unknown
started         : false
state           : Unknown
NAME              VALUE
----              -----
appliedLastSeqno: Unknown
appliedLatency  : Unknown
role            : Unknown
serviceName     : beta
serviceType     : Unknown
started         : false
state           : Unknown
Finished services command...
```

And observed below error from trepsvc log

```
Unable to start replication service beta.
Unable to instantiate replication service beta.
```

And if trying to make service online getting below output.

> ..........Operation failed: null

Answer (score 0):

Can You paste some more details from logs because i had same issues but i fixed it. my logs were giving errors on interface point. i resolved it by setting up hostname in /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the multi-master config using the following command, if that helps:

for multi master:

```
./tools/tpm install delta \
    --topology=all-masters \
    --install-directory=/opt/continuent \
    --replication-user=tungsten \
    --replication-password=secret \
    --datasource-mysql-conf=/home/6/mysql/my.cnf \
    --master=master1,master2,master3 \
    --members=master1,master2,master3 \
    --master-services=rho,theta,phi \
    --start
```

Where services,

1. Rho: Master-1: master; Master-2,3: slaves
2. Theta: Master-2: master; Master-1,3: slaves
3. Phi:Master-3: master; Master-2,1: slaves